# bypass cloudflare protection with casperjs or phantomjs while using tor proxy

Tags: proxy, casperjs, tor

I use tor to access casperjs via this socks proxy
my OS windows 10 x64

my test.js

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
verbose: true,
logLevel: 'error',
pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false, // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
    loadPlugins: false, // use these settings
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'
    }
});
var caturl = ('http://www.test.com');
casper.start(caturl, function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
casper.run();
```

result from my local machine

```
casperjs test.js
This Is Page Title
```

when open tor, and I'm sure its working fine also the socks proxy is working tested it before

```
casperjs  --proxy=127.0.0.1:9150 --proxy-type=socks5 test.js
Attention Required! | Cloudflare
```

the result as I see, that its want to solve recaptcha to open this site from cloudflare

**BUT**

when I open the tor browser, and open the link tested in casperjs, its open normally without any asking for recaptcha

**WHY**
 when open the link with casperjs ask for recaptcha , and when open the link with tor browser (same proxy IP used) it doesn't ask for recaptcha ?

is this related with useragent or what ?

Comment: It's usually based on the IP.  Are you sure your Tor browser doesn't have cloudflare's cookie saying you already passed verification?

Comment: threre is nothing happened while loading page with tor browser , its just open the page directly in 2 second or 3 only, also when open cookies from tor, there is nothing in it related to cloudflare or the website tested

Comment: There are ways to identify PhantomJS even with custom useragent. http://engineering.shapesecurity.com/2015/01/detecting-phantomjs-based-visitors.html Given that this is Cloudflare's bread abd butter I wouldn't be surprised if they implemented those techniques.

Comment: Is there anyway to take this off to scrap website  using cloudflare under attack mode with casperjs or any similar (with click ability) over tor proxy