# Convert cloudflare-challenge.js from phantomjs to casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to convert cloudflare-challenge.js

https://gist.github.com/antoligy/f4f084b87946f84a89b4

From working on phantomjs to working on casperjs

with phantomjs

```
phantomjs cf.js http://website.com
[{"domain":"website.com","expires":GMT","expiry":1486226610,"httponly":false,"name":"_gat","path":"/","secure":false,"value":"1"},
```

with casperjs

```
casperjs cf.js http://website.com
[]
```

I need it to migrate this method with casperjs , problem provided here
[bypass cloudflare protection with casperjs or phantomjs while using tor proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000392/bypass-cloudflare-protection-with-casperjs-or-phantomjs-while-using-tor-proxy)

Comment: edit with more details

Comment: I see edit, but I see no details :) What have you already tried on the way of converting the script? Also: why would you even need to convert it? It's pretty self-contained, you have PhantomJS already, just run getting cookies with PhantomJS first, then use them with CasperJS.

Comment: I want to migrate this method with my own js made with casperjs, my js project can't work on phantomjs, coz of that I need to convert this method to use it with my own script , this is example of what I have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000392/bypass-cloudflare-protection-with-casperjs-or-phantomjs-while-using-tor-proxy , how to use this script with my own one

Comment: I export cookies file from phantomjs and use with casperjs while using tor proxy, still face same problem Attention Required! | Cloudflare, all I need that how to use the same delay and method from phantomjs cloudflare-challenge.js to my project made with casperjs to bypass cloudflare protection

Comment: Well, CasperJS is using PhantomJS under its hood, so you **can** use the latter.

Comment: This is not Upwork, you have to write code yourself, we can help you if you're stuck somewhere. So what have you tried? (Please, show the code)

Comment: Thanks vaviloff for your help, the code same as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000392/bypass-cloudflare-protection-with-casperjs-or-phantomjs-while-using-tor-proxy , all I want to do the can open website using cloudflare under attack mode over tor proxy, exporting cookies with phantomjs and use it (casperjs  --proxy=127.0.0.1:9150 --proxy-type=socks5 --cookies-file=cookies.txt test.js) give same problem (Attention Required! | Cloudflare) 403 redirect

Comment: Why would you want to export cookies at all? Think: how does that script (exporting cookies) work?